# FPGA free tools for synthesis and simulation working on Windows 10

Tags: gratis, simulation

As a hobby, I return to programming FPGA systems. I am looking for a free tool for the synthesis and simulation of reprogrammable circuits that work for the Windows 10 operating system. At this point, it does not matter what manufacturer or family of reprogrammable circuits I will use. I just want to be able to do post-synthesis simulation and post-place-route simulation. I'm currently having trouble getting a license for the simulation tools since I'm not a student (I'm guessing this is a problem for the 'Active-HDL' product).

With many problems, I managed to install Xilinx_ISE_14.7_Win10_14.7_VM_0213_1 under Windows 10. Although I don't know if VW is a reasonable choice.

I live in Poland, I see that due to the change in US law, there are huge problems with making free software available outside the US. An example of such problems is Intel's FPGA programming tools.

What free simulation tool will allow me to recompile Xilnx libraries or will already have them compiled and work under Windows 10?

Maybe there is a better list of apps that meet my expectations?

Expectations:

1. Free
2. Availability in EU
3. Windows 10
4. post-synthesis simulation
5. post-place-route simulation

Comment: Your English is quite good!